# Spacewalk: How to create system groups in new Orginization?

Tags: centos, redhat, satellite

I am building a new Spacewalk server (running on CentOS7) based on the configuration of our current one. The current one is far out of date and the pxe boot is broken so I want to start fresh.

That being said, I have read in the Satellite manual that you should have multiple organizations. A default Spacewalk organization for management and then your other organizations (companies, locations etc).

I am having an issue when I create a new organization. When I log into it with the Organization Admin I create, I am unable to create system groups.

Looking at our current server, I see that all of my system groups are in this second organization. So it has to be possible. What am I missing?

I have tried making new users in both organizations, making new Orginization admins, giving new users full access with Spacewalk Admin privileges and I get nothing.

I can provide more information/screenshots if needed.

Thank you,

Greg9021

Comment: UPDATE: I have found the answer. When you are logged in with your Organization Admin, Click the Overview Tab then on the right side of the screen click the blue "Manage" button. This will take you to the System Set Manger where you can then create your groups.

Comment: You should enter the answer and mark it answered.